# Set default screen size in AIR

Tags: javascript, air, dreamweaver

I am writing an AIR application with HTML/JavaScript in Dreamweaver and I am trying to set the initial window size. I tried using this in the HTML:

```
<body onload="initialScreenSize(500,300)">
```

and then in the JavaScript:

```
function initialScreenSize(width,height)
{
       window.resizeTo(width,height);
}
```

This works but the screen initially displays at the default size (something like 800 x 600) then a fraction of a second later changes to what I specified above. I don't like the way this looks.

Is there any way to set the default screen size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where to set this:

In the Dreamweaver menu bar go to: Site/AIR Application Settings...

Then midway down the window there are window size settings.